# mysql substitution variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oracle

I don't really want to open a new question for such a basic question but I need help. Im studying mysql and just started with substitution variables

Consider this simple statement:

```
  SELECT empid, surname 
    from employees
    where
    empid = &empid
```

Oracle gives me the error *not all variables bound*. Please, could someone enlighten me as to what is wrong with my statement?

Comment: mysql variables use `@`, not `&`. where/how are you using this `&` notation?

Comment: this is pretty similar to the example in my textbook,using it in sql workshop, command editor

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See the Oracle Application Express docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/user.32/e13370/sql_proc.htm#AEUTL228

> Bind variables are prefixed with a colon.

So change your query to:

```
 SELECT empid, surname 
    from employees
    where
    empid = :empid
```

When you run the query, you will get a popup window asking you to supply the value of :empid.